# php mysql recordset filter

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

I'm doing something in php but I am pretty new to it so it might be a rookie question. In each case googling for it didn't quite get me a desired result.

In Classic ASP you can retreive a recordset from your database and then set a filter on that recordset so you don't have to query your database multiple times.
It would be done as so:

```
Set rst = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.Open objCmd
...
rst.Filter = "Variable=" & variable
```

However, I can't seem to find whether this functionality exists in php and if so, how to implement it.
I retrieve my recordset in php as follows:

```
$rst = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

In my iteration through this recordset I should be able to set a filter on a second recordset (created in the same way).

Thanks!

Comment: first of all, you are using `mysql` extension which is deprecated  and it's better to choose between `mysqli` and `pdo`. second, you can fetch data from your query to an array for example in `pdo` you can use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and then you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the results. please give it a try and if you hade any more question, you can update you post with your new questions.